# Crash in ios due to multiple background webservice call

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I have to call three web services in a view. I am using `ASIHttprequest` call. I will call each web service one after another. It causes a crash

```
-[INetServices respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12629a10
```

How can i overcome this bad request error.

```
HUDadmin = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];

[self.view addSubview:HUDadmin];
HUDadmin.delegate = self;
HUDadmin.labelText =@"Loading";
//[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:20];
[HUDadmin showWhileExecuting:@selector(adminCheck) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

where `adminCheck` is as follows:

```
-(void)adminCheck
{
    INetServices *inetadmin=[[INetServices alloc]init];

    NSString *response = [inetadmin doHTTPPostadmincheck:getUserId comm_id:str_commId];

    if (!response) {
        NSLog(@"response nil ");

        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *jsonarrayResponse=[response JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"Admin:%@",jsonarrayResponse);
    str_adminStatus = [jsonarrayResponse valueForKey:@"admin_status"];
    if ([[jsonarrayResponse valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]==TRUE)
    {
        if ([[jsonarrayResponse valueForKey:@"message"]isEqualToString:@"Admin user!."]==TRUE)
        {
            int_adminStatus=1;
        }
        else
        {
            int_adminStatus=0;
        }
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideProgress) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(CommunityDetailwebservice)
                           withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: If you add an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), that might help identify which line is causing the problem. Or share the stack trace with us. The only thing that looks suspect to me is that while you're in `showWhileExecuting`, you're calling `hideProgress`. What does that method do? Is that possibly trying to remove the view controller that used the HUD?

Comment: yes hide progess method used to hide Hud.then calling CommunityDetailwebservice..same process happens and in community detail webservice responce again a webservice is called....

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine precisely what the source of the zombie is on the basis of what's been provided thus far. An [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) or stack trace might narrow it down.

Having said that, I find the asynchronous calls to other methods from within the call to `showWhileExecuting` a little worrisome, especially since `hideProgress` is trying to hide the HUD you're currently showing.

I'd be inclined to refactor this code, and pass the HUD to the selector to a method that will run all three web services:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:hud];
[hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(performWebServiceRequests:) onTarget:self withObject:hud animated:YES];
```

That way, `performWebServiceRequests:` updates the HUD and performs the various synchronous web service requests:

```
- (void)performNetworkRequests:(MBProgressHUD *)hud
{
    hud.labelText = @"step 1";
    [self adminCheck];

    hud.labelText = @"step 2";
    [self communityDetailWebService];

    hud.labelText = @"step 3";
    [self thirdWebService];
}
```

If you needed the calling of a latter web service to be contingent upon the success of the prior ones, you could tweak `performWebServiceRequests` accordingly. For example, if these three web service methods returned `TRUE` upon success, or `FALSE` upon failure, you could then do something like:

```
- (void)performNetworkRequests:(MBProgressHUD *)hud
{
    hud.labelText = @"step 1";
    if (![self adminCheck])
        return;

    hud.labelText = @"step 2";
    if (![self communityDetailWebService])
        return;

    hud.labelText = @"step 3";
    [self thirdWebService];
}
```

Anyway, when you return from the `performWebServiceRequests` method, then the HUD will automatically be dismissed for you.

Comment: -(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request  this function makes the error when third webservice called....is that because of hud showWhileExecuting

Comment: @user3388273 You might want to update your question, sharing that method, too.